# Prove that $\gcd(6n-1, 2n-4) = 1$ or $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: Prove that if $n$ is an integer, then $\gcd(6n-1, 2n-4) = 1$ or $11$.

Would I have to use the Euclidean algorithm to solve this problem?

How would I go about finding values of $n$ afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $6n - 1 = 3 (2n-4) + 11$. Thus the GCD of $6n-1$ and $2n-4$ is the same as the GCD of $2n-4$ and $11$. The latter is easily seen to be either $1$ or $11$. Which of the two it is depends on the $n$: if $11$ divides $2n-4$ it is $11$ otherwise  it is $1$, and this could be expressed as a condition modulo $11$.

If you want you can see this as running the Euclidean algorithm.